# HowTo Chroot to BSD

Tags: freebsd, environment-variables, chroot, bsd, env

I recently tried FreeBSD `[9.2]`. I installed it but as i found out it doesn't install any bootloader by default.

So now i want to find out **HOW** it is possible to `chroot` to the installed BSD via a livecd or any other means. and if this livecd could be linux (I doubt that).

1. Do i need to mount `/proc` `/sys` and `/dev` partitions?
2. How to declare a sane `env` in `chroot` command?

PS: at the end of FreeBSD installation process, there was a nifty script that search my wireless and find out an access-point. then ask me about the password and connect me to it. what is the name of the script and could I run it from the command line?

Answer (score 4):

Yes; all the above is currect but here is a point missing here and that is being freebsd uses `/bin/csh` as the default environment and you should declare it in the chroot to work. if the `/bin/csh` didn't work try `/bin/sh`. something like this:

```
mkdir /mnt/freebsd
mount /dev/da0s1 /mnt/freebsd
chroot /mnt/freebsd /bin/env -i TERM=$TERM /bin/csh
```

Answer (score 2):

Boot with the FreeBSD [install media](http://www.freebsd.org/where.html).

You will be prompted for `<Install> < Shell > <Live CD>`

Select `<Live CD>`

From there you will get a shell and can mount your drives (`gpart list`) and do what you need to.

It's odd that you didn't get the freebsd boot code though as the install [would normally put it there for you](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/bsdinstall-partitioning.html#bsdinstall-part-review) if you use the guided partitioning tool. I'd suggest you do the install again rather than messing with booting off the Live CD.

The wireless network setup is a part of [`bsdinstall`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdinstall&sektion=8). You can run it with `bsdinstall netconfig`

Comment: Could you recommend up to date bsd livecd. the flavour doesn't matter much. but it should has a simple DE ( like `XFCE`, `LXDE`, `OpenBox` ...). and It should have ability to find wifi connection and connect to it with password.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used BSD before, but this shouldn't be too complicated.

All that is necessary is to boot your livecd, mount the partition you installed on and chroot to the mount point. This should be as simple as:

```
su
mount /dev/da0s1 /mnt
chroot /mnt
```

You will have to find the correct partition you installed on, `fdisk -s` should help with that (appears to be the equivalent of `fdisk -l` on Linux).

As for whether to mount `/proc`, `/dev` etc, it really depends on what you will be doing - if any of the programs you are running require files on these filesystems, then they will most likely fail. Doing simple installations shouldn't need these mounts. On the other hand running `update-grub` for the Debian GRUB2 bootloader requires all of these to be mounted as it does some advanced things like probing for other OSes. Unfortunately I can't comment for BSD bootloaders.

As for environment variables, these should be copied from your livecd environment which should be roughly the same as what you get if you boot the system. I wouldn't sweat about. If a program needs specific variables which aren't set, just run it with `var=value program` inside the `chroot` shell or use `export` (`help export`) before running.

Comment: First; as far as I know; the BSD is quite different from the Linux. But even with Linux you have to set a sane environment and then chroot to it. and Chroot to newly installed distro is to develop it. So you need `/proc` and `/dev` and also `/sys`. quite frankly you could do nothing without them.

Comment: You should still be able to run a shell without `/proc`, `/dev` or `/sys`. An issue should only arise if a program tries to access a file underneath one of them, in which case it obviously won't find it and will probably exit with an error.